# Follow touch point by sprite with rotation

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I've successfully implemented dragging a sprite on the screen, by simply remembering touch position on touchbegan and translating sprite by currentTouchPoint - startingTouchPoint, which gives me nice dragging. But now I want to sprite track my finger instead so it also should rotate. This would give me an advantage of making user able to rotate sprite as well as drag it around with just one finger.

I was getting unexpected results, but I've ran into this code:

http://www.freeactionscript.com/2011/01/mouse-follow-with-easing-smooth-rotation-v2/

There's a demo so you could try it on the browser.

It's pretty much the same I need except sprite should be a lot faster (near the finger all the time) and stop after reaching it's destination instead of orbiting around (while holding touch). I've tried to port it to cocos2d-x, but it doesn't work the same. Well, updatePosition() looks good, sprite is going where it should be pretty much, but updateRotation() is a total mess. It's rotating in strange directions and sometimes even makes a full very fast circle in opposite direction.

onTouchBegan:
`//check if any sprite is touched and then assign it to draggedItem`

onTouchMove:
`_destinationX = touchPoint.x;
_destinationY = touchPoint.y;`

onTouchEnd:
`//make draggedItem nullptr`

```
void CreatorScene::update(float delta){
    if(draggedItem != nullptr){
        updateItemPosition();
        updateItemRotation();
    }
}

void CreatorScene::updateItemRotation()
{
    // calculate rotation
    _dx = draggedItem->getPositionX() - _destinationX;
    _dy = draggedItem->getPositionY() - _destinationY;

    // which way to rotate
    float rad = atan2(_dy, _dx);
    if(_dy < 0) rad += 2 * M_PI;
    float rotateTo = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rad);

    // keep rotation positive, between 0 and 360 degrees
    if (rotateTo > draggedItem->getRotation() + 180) rotateTo -= 360;
    if (rotateTo < draggedItem->getRotation() - 180) rotateTo += 360;

    // ease rotation
    _trueRotation = (rotateTo - draggedItem->getRotation()) / ROTATE_SPEED_MAX;

    // update rotation
    draggedItem->setRotation(draggedItem->getRotation() + _trueRotation);
}

void CreatorScene::updateItemPosition()
{
    // check if mouse is down
//    if (_isActive)
//    {
        // update destination
//        _destinationX = stage.mouseX;
//        _destinationY = stage.mouseY;

        // update velocity
        _vx += (_destinationX - draggedItem->getPositionX()) / MOVE_SPEED_MAX;
        _vy += (_destinationY - draggedItem->getPositionY()) / MOVE_SPEED_MAX;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        // when mouse is not down, update velocity half of normal speed
//        _vx += (_destinationX - _player.x) / _moveSpeedMax * .25;
//        _vy += (_destinationY - _player.y) / _moveSpeedMax * .25;
//    }

    // apply decay (drag)
    _vx *= DECAY;
    _vy *= DECAY;

    // if close to target, slow down turn speed
    if (sqrtf((_dx*_dx)+(_dy*_dy)) < 50)
    {
        _trueRotation *= .5;
    }           

    // update position
    draggedItem->setPosition(draggedItem->getPosition() + Point(_vx, _vy));
}
```

What's wrong here? How can I achieve such a smooth movement?

Edit:
Functionality that I want to exactly achieve is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZouMyyNGG8
You can see it on 2:10.